# Deriving Inequalities for Binomial Terms of $(\alpha + \beta)^m$, $\alpha + \beta = 1$

Tags: inequality

Assume $\alpha + \beta = 1$, and one is trying to find a lower bound on the $k$th term in the binomial expansion of $(\alpha + \beta)^m$. The terms are of the form $\binom{m}{k} \alpha^k \beta ^{m-k}$.

Assume that $k \ll m \ll 1/\alpha$. More formally, and in [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $k = o(m)$ and $m = o(1/\alpha)$. Can we derive good lower bounds for the $k$th term in the binomial expansion? (When $m$ is large enough.)

PS 1: I read [upper and lower bounds to binomial coefficient](https://planetmath.org/UpperAndLowerBoundsToBinomialCoefficient) on PlanetMath, but couldn't figure out what to do.

PS 2: In fact, this question stem from the following (rather tight) inequality for large enough $n$'s:

$\binom{n^4}{n} \left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^n \left(1-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4-n} < \frac{1}{4 \sqrt n}$

in which $m = n^4$, $\alpha=1/n^3$, and $k=n$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks. I thing Stirling does the trick!